# Save data programmatically in a MVVM Devexpress project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I created a WPF MVVM project in Devexpress with the [Scaffolding wizard](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/mvvm-wpf.xml) and everything created works fine, I even modified the grids so they call the `SaveCommand` on `RowUpdated`.

Now I'm trying to insert new registers programmatically and my strategy was to get and instance of the `CollectionViewModel` from my model and use its `Save` method sending an object from the same model as a parameter.

I was reading [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument115231) guide but still couldn't find what i'm doing wrong.

This is the code

```
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.IdClient = 1;

        TransactionCollectionViewModel tcvm = TransactionCollectionViewModel.Create(UnitOfWorkSource.GetUnitOfWorkFactory());
        tcvm.Save(transaction);
```

and it gives me this error on the variable `tcvm` when calling the `Save` function

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=DevExpress.Mvvm.v16.1.DataModel
  StackTrace:
       at DevExpress.Mvvm.DataModel.RepositoryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`3.<GetProjectionPrimaryKey>b__0(TEntity x)
       at DevExpress.Mvvm.DataModel.RepositoryExtensions.GetProjectionValue[TEntity,TProjection,TEntityResult,TProjectionResult](TProjection value, Func`2 entityFunc, Func`2 projectionFunc)
       at DevExpress.Mvvm.DataModel.RepositoryExtensions.GetProjectionPrimaryKey[TEntity,TProjection,TPrimaryKey](IRepository`2 repository, TProjection projectionEntity)
       at DevExpress.Mvvm.DataModel.RepositoryExtensions.FindExistingOrAddNewEntity[TEntity,TProjection,TPrimaryKey](IRepository`2 repository, TProjection projectionEntity, Action`2 applyProjectionPropertiesToEntity)
       at DevExpress.Mvvm.ViewModel.CollectionViewModelBase`4.Save(TProjection projectionEntity)
       at Template.ViewModels.ClientCollectionViewModel..ctor(IUnitOfWorkFactory`1 unitOfWorkFactory) in C:\Users\edwin\Source\Workspaces\INVASST\Template\Template\ViewModels\Client\ClientCollectionViewModel.cs:line 37
       at ClientCollectionViewModel_97cd3897_6fb7_469b_9928_d61260161e61..ctor(IUnitOfWorkFactory`1 unitOfWorkFactory)
  InnerException:
```

I'm using Devexpress 16.1.5 and the project is using the [HybridApp](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17924) template

Answer (score 1):

> ... my strategy was to get an instance of the CollectionViewModel from my model and use its Save method sending an object from the same model as a parameter.

I'm afraid this strategy is wrong. You should use the `New()` command provided by the corresponding CollectionViewModel (bound to the Grid).
The real usage depends on your specific needs. In a simple case, you can just add a button above the grid and then bind the New command to this button.

Related DX support thread : [Batch Insert/ Edit with Master/Detail](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T260015)